# Não estou entendendo o retorno dessa adição em Python

Tags: python, matemática, operadores, sintaxe

O seguinte código está retornando uma resposta como se fossem duas strings coladas uma na outra(Ex: 3+5 = 35) em vez da soma dos dois valores digitados, alguem pode me ajudar?

```
op = input()

if op == 'A' or op == 'a':
    print('digite os números da operação')
    n1 = input()
    n2 = input()
    res = (n1+n2)
    print(res)
```

Comment: `input` retorna por padrão uma `string`, precisa converter para `int(input())`

Comment: como o amigo acima mencionou, a função input() retorna uma string, e por padrão o operador + concatena strings, convertendo pra int as strings passam a ser valores numéricos e assim o operador + passa a ser o de adição

Answer (score -2):

O input está recebendo os dados como String, você tem que especificar que quer receber números do tipo Int:

```py
op = input()

if op == 'A' or op == 'a':
    print('digite os números da operação')
    n1 = int(input())
    n2 = int(input())
    res = (n1+n2)
    print(res)
```